# Media query does not resizing fieldset and button

Tags: html, css, jsp, resize, media-queries

I'm trying to use media querys, but I have a problem. When I resized my window, it doesn't do anything when I resize the window, I try with different options, for example:

I have this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  #breakdown-search-clear-button {
    margin-left: 28% !important;
  }

  #historico-incidencias{
    width: 36.1% !important; 
    margin-left: 62% !important; 
    margin-top: -27.8% !important;
  }
```

}

or this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #breakdown-search-clear-button {
    margin-left: 28% !important;
  }

  #historico-incidencias{
    width: 36.1% !important; 
    margin-left: 62% !important; 
    margin-top: -27.8% !important;
  }
```

}

at the end of my css file. And it doesn't work. I try first with "@media screen" and then with "@media all", but it doesn't work in both cases when I resize the window.

Then I try to put  tag on my .jso file, as you can see on this example:

I write this  tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And, at the end of the  tag I write this:

```
<style>
    /* On screens that are 600px wide or less, the background color is olive */
    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
      #breakdown-search-clear-button {
        margin-left: 28% !important;
      }

      #historico-incidencias{
        width: 36.1% !important; 
        margin-left: 62% !important; 
        margin-top: -27.8% !important;
      }
    }
</style>
```

But it doesn't do anything when I resize the window as on the css file.

HTML elements:

```
        <div id="breakdown-search-clear-button" class="roundedButtonMin roundedButtonRight deleteBG" style="margin-left: 24% !important; margin-top: 1% !important;"></div> 

<fieldset style="width: 46.1%; margin-left: 52%; margin-top: -23%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" id="historico-incidencias">
                        <legend>Histórico</legend>
                        <div id="listHistoricalIncidences"></div>
                    </fieldset>
```

Anyone can help me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Sharing your html would be nice:)

Comment: i cannot share all the html file, but i add the html elements that I want to resize

Comment: In your case i think whats happening after the window is resized is the problem, I got no clue what you want to acheive but the query is working

Comment: I want to resize a table and change a button location, but it doesn't do anything